# Interpolating Maximum function with symmetric polynomials

Tags: symmetric-functions, interpolation

Let $n$ and $p$ be two positive integers. Consider the function
$$\max_{n,p}:\{0,\dots,n\}^p\to\{0,\dots,n\}$$
that computes the maximum of a $p$-tuple of integers in the range $\{0,\dots,n\}$. Are there explicit expressions for symmetric polynomials $P_{n,p}\in\mathbb{Q}[\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_p]$ such that $P_{n,p}(\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_p)$ interpolates $\displaystyle\max_{n,p}$? Here the $\sigma_i$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials.

---

The case $p=2$ can be done by hand :
$P_{n,2}(\sigma_1,\sigma_2)$ can be described by the formula
$$\sum_{s=0}^{2n}
    \prod_{\substack{a=0\\a\neq s}}
    \frac{\sigma_1-a}{s-a}
    \cdot\left(
    \sum_{i=\max\{s-n,0\}}^{\lfloor s/2\rfloor}
    (s-i)
    \prod_{\substack{j=\max\{s-i,0\}\\j\neq i}}^{\lfloor s/2\rfloor}
    \frac{\sigma_2-j(s-j)}{i(s-i)-j(s-j)}
    \right)$$
Which you obtain by interpolating the maximum functions along the ``antidiagonals'' $x+y=s$, $0\leq x,y\leq n$.

---

As far as I can tell, the result from [Interpolation for Symmetric Functions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870896900043) is inapplicable here.

I'm interested in this question to study networks. The special case where $n=p=2^N$ is of particular interest to me. Furthermore, I want to allow more invariant polynomials, specifically those that are invariant under a 2-Sylow group of $\mathfrak{S}_n$.

Answer (score 1):

The following would be proof of existence of such polynomial rather then actual construction (and it's a generalization of your approach).

Define $S_i$ as a set of all possible values $\sigma_i(a)$ for $a\in\{0,1,\ldots, n\}^p$ and define $A=\{0,1\ldots, n\}^p$
Consider any $p$-tuple $a=(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_p)\in A$ and define a polynomial $L_a\in\mathbb{Q}[\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\ldots,\sigma_p]$ as follows
$$
L_a=\prod_{i=1}^{p}\prod_{t_i\in S_i\backslash\{s_i\}}\frac{\sigma_i-t_i}{s_i-t_i},
$$
where $s_i=\sigma_i(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_p)$ ($L_a$ is well-defined due to Vieta's theorem).
The main property of $L_a$ is that $L_a(a)=1$ and $L_a(b)=0$ for any $p$-tuple $b\in A\backslash \{a\}$.

Now, we can define 
$$
P_{n,p}=\sum_{a\in A}\max\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_p\}\cdot L_a.
$$
Clearly, $P_{n,p}\in \mathbb{Q}[\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\ldots,\sigma_p]$ and $P_{n,p}(a)=\max\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_p\}$ for any $a\in A$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, that works :) and generalizes my own approach. Ideally I would like something "explicit" (the aim is to plug in special random variables and to compute the expectation). But there might be no ``better'' formula.

Comment: The question of existence needs no proof : just take any multivariate polynomial that interpolates the max function, and average it over the symmetric group. The resulting polynomial is symmetrical (and thus a polynomial in the $\sigma_i$) interpolates the max function;

Comment: Yes, indeed, existence is trivial.